# Sorting a list of list of tuples

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sorting, tuples

I am trying to sort a list of list of tuples based on the values in the last tuple.

```
[[(3, 1005), (3, 1050), (3, 945), (4, 1510), (13, 4510)],
[(3, 1000), (3, 955), (4, 1501), (5, 1900), (15, 5356)],
[(3, 945), (3, 955), (3, 901), (5, 1900), (14, 4701)],
[(3, 1000), (3, 945), (3, 901), (5, 1900), (14, 4746)],
[(3, 1000), (3, 1050), (3, 955), (4, 1500), (13, 4505)],
[(3, 1050), (3, 955), (4, 1511), (5, 1905), (15, 5421)]]
```

Specifically I want the final tuples to be sorted in ascending order by the first element, and in descending order by the second element.

I was able to sort the last tuple using this code:

```
validCombo = sorted(validCombo, key=operator.itemgetter(4))
```

BUT unable to reverse the order of the last element in the tuple. I need the following output:

```
[[(3, 1005), (3, 1050), (3, 945), (4, 1510), (13, 4510)],
[(3, 1000), (3, 1050), (3, 955), (4, 1500), (13, 4505)],
[(3, 1000), (3, 945), (3, 901), (5, 1900), (14, 4746)],
[(3, 945), (3, 955), (3, 901), (5, 1900), (14, 4701)],
[(3, 1050), (3, 955), (4, 1511), (5, 1905), (15, 5421)],
[(3, 1000), (3, 955), (4, 1501), (5, 1900), (15, 5356)]]
```

Soon I will be adding a 3rd value to the final tuple and sorting a third time. I am looking forward to your comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) two times.

```
validCombo = sorted(validCombo, key=lambda elem: elem[numDays][1], reverse = True)
validCombo = sorted(validCombo, key=lambda elem: elem[numDays][0])
```

`sorted` is guaranteed to be a [stable sort](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/247441), so we can use it in your case.

[Demo](https://ideone.com/76rmF3)

Answer (score 2):

You can make a combined key of both elements of the tuple:

```
sorted(data, key=lambda q: (q[4][0],-q[4][1]))
```